# Dividing Number into Segments of knowing Ranges using Python

Tags: python, numbers, iteration

I have a number like `9970024` that comes from a total number of `249250621` and I would like to divide the `9970024` number into segments of equal range. That is, `0-9970024` is one iteration that I want to do and then next `9970024 +1 to 19940049 (from 9970025+9970024)` until it reaches to the total number which is `249250621`. How can I do such thing using python.

My initial try is as follows:

```
j = 0
x = 9970024
total = 249250621
while (j <= total):
 for i in range(j,x):
  j = j +1
 j = i+1
 x = x+j
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's use some smaller numbers for clarity.

```py
total = 25
fragment = 10
for start in xrange(0, total, fragment):
    print "start = ", start
    for i in range(start, min([start + fragment, total])):
        print i
```

Output:

```
start = 0
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
start = 10
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
start = 20
20
21
22
23
24
```

Comment: I would recommend the use of `xrange` if Python 2.x is being used, especially as large numbers are involved. [xrange vs range](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/94935/what-is-the-difference-between-range-and-xrange-functions-in-python-2-x)

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way of looking at this could be to simply iterate the whole range but determine when a segment boundary is reached.

```
total = 249250621       
segment = total / 25        # 9970024 

for j in xrange(0, total+1):
    if j % segment == 0:
        print "%u - start of segment" % j
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(0,249250621,9970024):
    for j in range(i,i+9970024+1):
        pass
```

You can try this.Here `i` will increase by `9970024` everytime.And j will loop for `9970024` times.

Comment: This won't stop at the `total` number (= approx. 25 x 9970024). - Ok, now it will. :)