# Why is the program giving MemoryError? Language:Python

Tags: python-2.7

My program is to find the number of perfect squares between any two given numbers(both inclusive)

```
# Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT
import math
t=int(raw_input())
for i in range(0,t):
    count=0
    s,e=raw_input().strip().split(' ')
    s,e=[int(s),int(e)]
    for j in range(s,e+1):
        if math.sqrt(j)==math.floor(math.sqrt(j)):
            count+=1
    print count
```

When the input is for example:

> 3
>
> 59 999999922
>
> 9 999999966
>
> 12 999999988

The error that pops up is:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "solution.py", line 8, in
>   
>       for j in range(s,e+1): MemoryError

Why is this error coming up? and how can I solve it?
Sorry I am new to this stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

`range()` *creates a list in memory* and if the value of `t` gets big enough you are running our of memory. Use *lazy evaluation*, [replace `range()` with `xrange()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94935/what-is-the-difference-between-range-and-xrange-functions-in-python-2-x).