# Calculating pi with Leibniz Formula

Tags: python, math, pi

I am trying to calculate pi using the Leibniz formula. However, my code seems to always produce '0.19634952834936123' at the end, which is obviously not pi.

Code:

```
import math
x = 0
y = 0
for t in range(1,10000001):
    if t % 2 != 0:
        y += 1
        if y % 2 != 0:
            x += 1/t
        else:
            x -= 1/t
    else:
        pass
print(x/4)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This sum converges to π/4, not to 4π.  Therefore, you want to use the result

```
x * 4
```

Not

```
x / 4
```

Other than that, your code is working OK.

Answer (score 2):

My IDE took a while to run your code. [Additionally, if you're running that code in Python 2 that `range` expression is going to use up *a lot* of memory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/94962/1636276). If you'd like, here's an alternate approach that lazily generates the Leibniz formula terms to estimate pi. Python's generator functions seem ideally suited to this sort of task.

```
def estimate_pi(num_terms):
    return 4 * sum(x for x in generate_leibniz_terms(num_terms))


def generate_leibniz_terms(num_terms):
    denominator = 1
    sign = 1

    for _ in range(num_terms):
        yield sign * (1 / denominator)
        sign = -sign
        denominator += 2


print(estimate_pi(100))
```

**Output**

```
3.1315929035585537
```

Comment: You may assume Python 3, because otherwise the division `1/t` would have returned 0 and the original code could not have produced 0.1963..

Comment: That is not a very good approximation for pi.  Two accurate digits hardly seems worth the effort.

Comment: @duffymo It was just an example to demonstrate. What I have demonstrates the point fine, and all that's required to get a more accurate estimate is to increase the argument passed to `estimate_pi`.

Comment: Just checked the convergence of the Leibniz formula: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_%CF%80.  Sub-linear convergence explains it.  I expected something like Taylor series for sine and cosine, which both exhibit quadratic convergence.  I feared that the low accuracy reflected on your solution, but that does not appear to be the case.

Comment: @duffymo Yeah that makes sense. I have to bump the number up quite high to get anything much more accurate.