# How to speed up Numpy sum and Python for-loop?

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, jit

I have 2 codes that do almost the same thing.

code 1:

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np

m = 1
gamma = 1
lam = 1
alpha = 1
step_num = 2 ** 16
dt = 0.02


def E_and_x(x0):
    xi = x0
    vi = 0
    f = 0
    xsum = 0
    Ei, xavg = 0, 0
    for i in range(step_num):
        vi += f / m * dt / 2
        xi += vi * dt
        f = - gamma * xi - lam * xi ** 2 - alpha * xi ** 3
        vi += f / m * dt / 2
        Ei = 1 / 2 * m * vi ** 2 + 1 / 2 * gamma * xi ** 2 + \
            1 / 3 * lam * xi ** 3 + 1 / 4 * alpha * xi ** 4
        xsum += xi
        xavg = xsum / (i + 1)
    return Ei, xavg

E, x = [], []
for x0 in np.linspace(0, 1, 40):
    mdresult = E_and_x(x0)
    E.append(mdresult[0])
    x.append(mdresult[1])
```

code 2:

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
from numba import jit

time = 50
niter = 2 ** 16  # number of iterations
t = np.linspace(0, time, num=niter, endpoint=True)


class MolecularDynamics(object):
    def __init__(self, time, niter, initial_pos):
        self.position = np.array([])
        self.velocity = np.array([])
        self.energy = np.array([])
        self.x_average = np.array([])
        self.vel = 0  # intermediate variable
        self.force = 0  # intermediate variable
        self.e = 0  # intermediate energy
        self.initial_pos = initial_pos  # initial position
        self.pos = self.initial_pos
        self.time = time
        self.niter = niter
        self.time_step = self.time / self.niter
        self.mass = 1
        self.k = 1  # stiffness coefficient
        self.lamb = 1  # lambda
        self.alpha = 1  # quartic coefficient

    @jit
    def iter(self):
        for i in np.arange(niter):
            # step 1 of leap frog
            self.vel += self.time_step / 2.0 * self.force / self.mass
            self.pos += self.time_step * self.vel
            # step 2 of leap frog
            self.force = - self.k * self.pos - self.lamb * self.pos ** 2 - self.alpha * self.pos ** 3
            self.vel += self.time_step / 2.0 * self.force / self.mass

            # calculate energy
            self.e = 1 / 2 * self.mass * self.vel ** 2 + \
                     1 / 2 * self.k * self.pos ** 2 + \
                     1 / 3 * self.lamb * self.pos ** 3 + \
                     1 / 4 * self.alpha * self.pos ** 4

            self.velocity = np.append(self.velocity, [self.vel])  # record vel after 1 time step
            self.position = np.append(self.position, self.pos)  # record pos after 1 time step
            self.energy = np.append(self.energy, [self.e])  # record e after 1 time step
            self.x_average = np.append(self.x_average, np.sum(self.position) / (i + 1))


mds = [MolecularDynamics(time, niter, xx) for xx in np.linspace(0, 1, num=40)]
[md.iter() for md in mds]  # loop to change value
mds_x_avg = [md.x_average[-1] for md in mds]
mds_e = [md.e for md in mds]
```

Well, the main difference is code 2 uses OO, Numpy and JIT. However, code 2 is much much slower than code 1 (it takes many minutes to compute).

```
In [1]: %timeit code_1
10000000 loops, best of 3: 25.7 ns per loop
```

By profiling I know the bottleneck is `iter()` function and more specifically, on `append` and `sum`. But using Numpy is as far as I can do,
I wonder why code 2 is much more slower and how can I speed it up?

Comment: Whenever you use `np.append` you will throw away the famous numpy-speed.

Comment: Unless you can turn your problem into calculations between vectors/matrices/tensors, numpy won't magically make your code faster. You may try pypy or cython to JIT/AOT compile the code though.

Comment: @kennytm I'm sorry that code 2 is already run in JIT.

Comment: For simple access and removal numpy arrays are almost 10 times slower that the native python lists. Keeping this in mind you just have to make a choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to what MSeifert said, you can preallocate the arrays to the correct size instead of appending to them. So instead of creating them like this:

```
self.position = np.array([])  # No
```

you would write:

```
self.position = np.zeros(niter) # Yes
```

Then instead of appending like this:

```
self.velocity = np.append(self.velocity, [self.vel])
```

you would fill in like this:

```
self.velocity[i] = self.vel
```

This avoids reallocating the arrays at each iteration (You can do exactly the same with raw python lists BTW using `array = [someValue]*size`).

**Vectorizability**

I went on wondering about vectorizability of the OP's algorithm. It seems that it isn't vectorizable. To quote the [Cornell Virtual Workshop](https://cvw.cac.cornell.edu/vector/coding_dependencies) :

> **Read after write ("flow") dependency.**
>   This kind of dependency is not vectorizable. It occurs when the values of variables in a particular loop iteration (the "read") are determined by a previous loop iteration (the "write").

The "flow" dependency is seen in the loop, where several members' values are determined by the previous state of that same member. For example:

```
self.vel += self.time_step / 2.0 * self.force / self.mass
```

Here, `self.force` is from the previous iteration and was computed from the previous `self.vel`.

Comment: But one still has to pay the "unboxing" cost each iteration when you set the item! It might perform better for `position` because `np.sum(position)` is faster than `sum` but for all other "arrays" it's just unnecessary overhead.

Comment: Yes, but I don't see how to avoid the unboxing overhead unless the algorithm can be vectorized. I haven't found a way to do so, nor found info about general proof-of-vectorizability. This answer just avoids allocation/copy/deletion of the array on each iteration, which is just one step in the optimization process.

Comment: Yes and I like your answer. It was only meant as comment (for future readers), not as criticism. :)

Comment: No problem, I didn't take it as such :) I was really wondering if there were ways to avoid the unboxing in numpy.

Comment: Yes, after I changed `self.position = np.array([])` to `self.position = np.zeros(niter)`, and `self.velocity = np.append(self.velocity, [self.vel])` to `self.velocity[i] = self.vel`, there was noticeable speed-up.

Comment: And I think the bottleneck is this statement: `self.x_average = np.append(self.x_average, np.sum(self.position) / (i + 1))`. After I added a statement `self.x_sum = 0` in `__init__` method, and 2 statements: `self.x_sum += self.pos` as well as `self.x_average[i] = self.x_sum / (i + 1)` in `iter()` method, there was another boost in speed. I should have thought about this!

Comment: Seems like a reasonable thing to do. While we're optimizing, we can do better memory-wise: `np.arange` will create a full table of 2**16 integers. Which might not be dramatic. But still, here it is not needed. For Python 2.7 you can use [xrange](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/94935/what-is-the-difference-between-range-and-xrange-functions-in-python-2-x), for Python 3, good old [range](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=range#func-range).

Answer (score 4):

You did something wrong with your timings, just testing your first code (slightly modified):

```
from __future__ import division


def E_and_x(x0):
    m = 1
    gamma = 1
    lam = 1
    alpha = 1
    step_num = 2 ** 13   # much less iterations!
    dt = 0.02

    xi = x0
    vi = 0
    f = 0
    xsum = 0
    Ei, xavg = 0, 0
    for i in range(step_num):
        vi += f / m * dt / 2
        xi += vi * dt
        f = - gamma * xi - lam * xi ** 2 - alpha * xi ** 3
        vi += f / m * dt / 2
        Ei = 1 / 2 * m * vi ** 2 + 1 / 2 * gamma * xi ** 2 + \
            1 / 3 * lam * xi ** 3 + 1 / 4 * alpha * xi ** 4
        xsum += xi
        xavg = xsum / (i + 1)
    return Ei, xavg
```

The timings are **not** in the nanosecond regime:

```
%timeit [E_and_x(x0) for x0 in np.linspace(0, 1, 40)]  # 1 loop, best of 3: 3.46 s per loop
```

However if [numba](/questions/tagged/numba) would be an option I would definetly advise to jit the `E_and_x` functions:

```
import numba as nb

numbaE_and_x = nb.njit(E_and_x)

numbaE_and_x(1.2)  # warmup for the jit
%timeit [numbaE_and_x(x0) for x0 in np.linspace(0, 1, 40)]  # 100 loops, best of 3: 3.38 ms per loop
```

It's already 100 times faster. If you run the first code with PyPy (or Cythonize it) you should get similar results.

Apart from that:

- `np.append` is a terrible option. Because `np.append`, `np.concatenate`, `np.stack` (all variants) need to allocate a new array and copy all other arrays into it! And you don't do anything with these arrays, just append to them. So the only thing you do with numpy is something that numpy is really bad at!
- Check if you can **vectorize** any of the calculations using numpy-arrays (without append, etc.).
- And if it's still to slow all these `self.xxx` attribute accesses are slow, better to read them once and set them again later.