# How do I make my python program get the index of a string?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, indexof

I want my python 2.7 program to get the index of specific characters in a string. So like this:

Get the index of the [ and ] brackets in any string. For example:

```
"Hello World [These brackets] Hello World"
```

The program should return 12 and 27. Is there any way to make my python program to do this? If not, then I'm out of luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One naive approach which you can see but still I prefer to use indexof function:

```
>>> a = "Hello World [These brackets] Hello World"
>>> for i in xrange(len(a)):
...     if a[i] == '[' or a[i] == ']':
...             print i
... 
12
27
```

Comment: Can I change xrange to range, or is xrange there for a reason?

Comment: Sometimes it's better to use xrange over range but still you can use range there is no problem in that. Try to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/94935/what-is-the-difference-between-range-and-xrange-functions-in-python-2-x

Answer (score 3):

The `indexof` function in python is [index](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.index):

```
>>> "Hello World [These brackets] Hello World".index('[')
12

>>> "Hello World [These brackets] Hello World".index(']')
27
```

Answer (score 1):

What about index?

```
text = "Hello World [These brackets] Hello World"
idx1 = text.index("[")?
idx2 = text.index("]")?
```

Warning, this returns only the first match.