# in python what does range really do?

Tags: python, range

I'm new to python and trying to learn by consulting various sources.

There is a python manual at

http://www.physics.nyu.edu/pine/pymanual/html/chap3/chap3_arrays.html

which contains the following paragraph

---

> 3.2.2. Creating and modifying lists
>
> Python has functions for creating and augmenting lists. The most
>   useful is the range function, which can be used to create a uniformly
>   spaced sequence of integers. The general form of the function is
>   range([start,] stop[, step]), where the arguments are all integers;
>   those in square brackets are optional:
>
> ```
> In [26]: range(10)      # makes a list of 10 integers from 0 to 9
> Out[26]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
> ```

---

So according to this source, range(10) creates a list. However when I run range(10) on anaconda3 I get

```
In [1]: range(10)
Out[1]: range(0, 10)
```

I'm not sure what range(0,10) is, but whatever it is, it looks very different from the above. What's going on?

Comment: what version are you using?

Comment: The manual is for Python 2, but you are using Python 3. `range` in Python 3 is much like `xrange` in Python 2. For that, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/94935/1639625

Comment: The correct reference is this: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range